# Replacement deprecated TabActivity with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, deprecated

i develop an application on android which is thus structured:
[image]

Activity 1, Activity 2, ..., Activity n - are tabs with related Activity.

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Resources res = getResources();        
    View view = null;        
    Context ctx = MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();

    TabSpec startspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Login");
    view = prepareTabView(ctx, "Login", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_bkg),  R.drawable.tab_files_selector);
    startspec.setIndicator(view).setContent(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    tabHost.addTab(startspec);
```

TabActivity content view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/title_band"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

My problem is:

How replace TabActivity with FragmentActivity or another else, so I use tabs with all the same activities ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you base your solution on the Action Bar (or Action Bar Sherlock ) and move your tabs to the top. I suggest a FragmentActivity (or SherlockFragmentActivity)  with a Fragment for each tab. I have done this in my app and the programming is straightforward and well-documented. I suggest you
start by looking at this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I implemented the solution suggested.